# How can I call a url from c# code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

How can I call a web api url from a csharp console application.

```
"/api/MemberApi"
```

I don't need anything back from the server. It just needs to be called and the Web API method will execute some code. Although it would be good to record if the call succeeded.

Comment: You can use `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` which are generally used to make any web service call. I do not have access to VS so cannot give an example. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435941/why-is-my-httpwebrequest-post-method-to-my-webapi-server-failing)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61664627/3596441

Answer (score 37, accepted):

WebClient class is what you need.

```
var client = new WebClient();
var content = client.DownloadString("http://example.com");
```

[Example of using WebClient in a console app](http://www.dotnetperls.com/webclient)

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can also use HttpWebRequest if you need to deal with a low level of abstraction but WebClient is a higher-level abstraction built on top of HttpWebRequest to simplify the most common tasks.

Comment: @Black Since c# 3.0 released in 2007

Comment: Shouldn't it be wrapped in a `using` clause?

Answer (score 9):

Use the `HttpWebRequest`

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.url.com/api/Memberapi") as HttpWebRequest;
//optional
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

Use the response to see if it was successfull or not. There are several Exceptions that can be raised (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx), which would show you, why your call has failed.