# How can I execute an url call from C# code on a ASP website on a ASCX page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, url, custom-protocol

I need to call a Custom protocol (something like: "custom:signDocs?param1=value?param2=value") that is registered on a client.

I have a working one that is executed via JavaScript on a button click.

But I need to call the url to execute the program I have on the clients pc.

The program is for signing documents and sending them back to the server, and, in the code I have a 15min timer that waits for the status of the documents to change to signed then it shows the documents to the user.

I also tried using webrequest:

```
    //Method that uses the webrequest
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("customProtocolName", new PrototipoIDPTRequestCreator());
        System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(protocolUrlWithParams);
        var aux = req.GetResponse();
    }

    internal class CustomRequestCreator : System.Net.IWebRequestCreate
    {
        public WebRequest Create(Uri uri)
        {
            return new CustomWebRequest(uri);
        }
    }

    class CustomWebRequest: WebRequest
    {
        public override Uri RequestUri { get; }
        public CustomWebRequest(Uri uri)
        {
            RequestUri = uri;
        }
    }
```

But this does nothing, I do not know it its even the right path...

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use HTTP client, make sure your quest adhere to cross-origin and authentication.

Comment: Can I call a custom protocol through an url with http client? can you foward me to some docs or examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpClient from `System.Net.Http` like the following example.

Simple get call from a test api endpoint.

```cs
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("YOUR_BASE_URL"); //https://localhost:8000
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/test"); //api uri
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
```

**Note:** For more details refer, [HttpClient Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Im not calling an API, Im calling a Custom/Pluggable Protocol, something like "MyProtocolName:Param1=value1&param2=value2"